# loading image from url ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an image from a url e.g.

https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/638751551457103872/KN-NzuRl.png

but in my code on my device i did this

```
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/638751551457103872/KN-NzuRl.png" />
```

but it returns nothing and doesnt display the picture but if i try it on a browser, the image displays.

Any help on this?

Comment: Try using InAppBrowser cordova plugin

Comment: Are you sure your CSP allows it? Are you using the Whitelist plugin if on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. As James_Parsons commented, you need to use the [Whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) if on Android. In my case, it was already installed and I had this issue anyway. So I needed to reset the Android platform plugin installation by entering in the console:

```
$ionic state reset
```

As the Android platform was added after all plugins were already installed, it seems like not all plugins were included (like Whitelist).

After running this command and re-deploying the app to my phone, the images loaded without any problem.

I also added "android" in the "cordovaPlatforms" key inside my package.json file, as it was not already added, before running this command.

```
"cordovaPlatforms": ["android"]
```